# Access print jobs from queue

Tags: c#, .net, printing, queue, postscript

Previously I'd asked about adding my c# windows app as virtual printer. I managed to get it done with RedMon and Ghostscript. Now when I press `Ctrl + P` the control is transferred to my app and i need the particular job as input to my app from the job queue. It seems it is possible to convert the postscript to any format, so how do I get this postscript file of the job.
OR
My app can convert .PS files to any format with the help of GhostScript, and I need to find the postscript of a job. How can this be done? Or Where can I find these PostScript Files of a particular print job.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: I ve been trying to get the post script, but all i could get was details other than this post script file.

Comment: I never knew using caps is considered shouting. Sorry I will keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: @Marco, can u help me in this?